# Ask for attachment on form (Paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Foreword: I'm a **REAL** rails newbie. I'm developing my first web application with it and therefore even basic concepts are hard to understand for me.

Having said thay, my problem:

I'm planning to use Paperclip (and Paperclip only) to store pdfs in my applications (since I'm expecting the pdfs to be around 0.5mb). The tutorial on Paperclip's github didn't one thing clear for me:

- How do I ask (and actually save) an attachment in my form?

Thank you very much, I really couldn't solve those two problems on my own.

EDIT: This is what I tried

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :pdf %>
  <%= f.file_field :pdf %>
</div>
```

The button to attach a file is there but it seems that it just doesn't work and the file isn't saved.

EDIT2:
    Following the suggested solution, now my server is indeed saving the pdfs I attach to my form.

Now I want to understand why the associated url (from a pdf) sends me direct to a page where the system asks where to save the pdf (aka it's downloading it automatically). Here goes the associated part of the code:

```
<td><%= (link_to 'Related file', task.pdf.url, :target => "_blank") if task.pdf.exists? %></td>
```

This is located inside app/views/tasks/index.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration to add the pdf attachment to a table (In this example I am adding the attachment PDF to a `Documents` table) should look like this:

```
class AddAttachmentPdfToDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :documents do |t|
      t.attachment :pdf
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :documents, :pdf
  end
end
```

You need to run `rake db:migrate` after you create this migration so that the pdf column actually gets added to the table.

Your Model code for paperclip (Again, I'm using A `documents` model for example) should look something like this:

```
has_attached_file :pdf, :use_timestamp => false
validates_attachment_content_type :pdf, :content_type => ['application/pdf', 'text/plain']
```

To add a pdf, you need to add an input to your form, for example this is the loop to use to ask for a pdf attachment:

```
<%= form_for @document do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :title, label: "Title" %>

    <%= f.input :pdf, label: "Upload document:" %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

In your controler (again using `documents` as the controler) you need to pass the params `:pdf`. Your private method would look something like:

```
def documents_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:title, :pdf)
end
```

Note, I am using `document` as my controller, model, form etc, so if you are using a different name you need to change that.
If you have problems leave a comment and I will try to help

Comment: That certainly did it! I don't yet fully grasp everything I did but thank you, I will get there.

EDIT: One more question, though: My 'view' now has a url link to my attached pdf. The only problem is, when I click it, it opens a new tab already asking me to the save pdf. How can I make it only show me, without asking for download or save?

Comment: I'm not too sure what your asking. Are you wanting the pdf to download directly, instead of opening in a new tab?

Comment: Quite the opposite, I want it to open in a new tab and just that. In it's actual form it's opening already with the 'save file' dialogue where you pick the location to save.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the link code for the pdf in your view file?

Comment: Done, waiting for you to check it out :)

Comment: The link that i use is: `<%= link_to "Download", document.pdf(:original, false) %>`

Try to use this for yours so it would be: `<%= link_to 'Related file', task.pdf(:original, false) %>`

Let me know if it works

Comment: Now it's doing the same thing as before, but doesn't even open a new tab to do that (it opens in the current one). Perhaps it's a OS issue?

Comment: Yes it seems it has something to do with your broswer. Browser config usually determines what happens when a pdf/document is opened